# Repeater ItemDataBound Complete Trigger

Tags: asp.net, repeater

Hi I have a Repeater and I am doing various things during the ItemDataBound event.  My Repeater is in a control.  What I am noticing is that the things that are supposed to happen in the ItemDataBound event happen after the Page_Load of the page hosting the control.  Is there a way to use some sort of ItemDataBoundComplete trigger so I can do other things on my page after the events of the ItemDataBound have taken place?  Thanks, please let me know if I have not been clear.

[Edit] I have controls that are being bound to the ItemDataBound and they are not available until after the Page_Load for the page hosting the control.

[Solution] (In my case):

In my page I used the following:
Control.Page.LoadComplete += new EventHandler(Control_LoadComplete);

Then I performed what I had to do in that event.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of things? You can override the OnPreRenderComplete method, which is called immediately before the page renders.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change to a ListView, which is support as much flexibility in the html, and use the DataBound event (which is called after the whole ListView has finished data binding).